# z-index not working even when positioning is set

Tags: html, css

As the title says I need that the div layers that shows when you hover over the map icons (http://goo.gl/Zn5CPL) to always be in front of the the other elements. As you can see when you resize the the window a bit smaller the menu a tags override the map popups as well as the text at the bottom of the screen.

This occurs even if I set positioning as relative on the a tags.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Your popup always stays on top for me on Firefox

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works as intened in Firefox, too.

Comment: Yes. Works in Firefox, doesnt work in Google Chrome. Happens the way the OP says in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `z-index: 99999;` to .hotspot-container. This would make it appear on top of menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
.hotspot-container{
z-index:9999;
position:relative;
}
```